# combobox shows value that isn't in the datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox (using databindings)

I load the combobox values as follows:

```
cb.BeginUpdate();
cb.DisplayMember = "Display";
cb.ValueMember = "Value";
cb.DataSource = cbvalues.GetBindingTable(true);
if (cb.Items != null && cb.Items.ValueList != null)
    cb.Items.ValueList.FormatFilteredItems = DefaultableBoolean.True;
cb.EndUpdate();
```

the `cbvalues` list contains several members (for example true/false/both)

the databindings occur as follows:

```
cb.DataBindings.Add("Value",
          _data,
          _data.GetPropertyName(bo => bo.cbvalue),
          false,
          DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged).BindingComplete += someotherfunctionname;
```

Now for the sake of reason, I for example always get the value Unknown from my object.

I would like to have my combobox showing nothing at all, just an empty combobox. Instead I get the value 'Unknown' in it. How can I disable this kind of behaviour.